# Remove local changes from DataGrid in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, flash-builder, flex4.5, advanceddatagrid

I am working Apache Flex 4.11 web application. I have a DataGrid which has item renderer for change the record. Now I change the record in the Datagrid using item renderer. Now there is a cancel button out side the DataGrid when I click on that it should remove the local changes(which I have done it for change the record) and show the original data which is showing before the change.

How can I do that.

Thanks
Bikrant Singh

Comment: mx or spark datagrid?, restoring a single cell, or row, or the entire dataset in the grid? Is the dataProvider an ArrayCollection?

Comment: mx AdvanceddataGrid, we need to restore entire dataset in the grid. The dataProvider is VectorCollection.

Comment: Without seeing your code and I haven't use apache flex, I think that..
First, clone the original dataProvider(VectorCollection).
If user clicks cancel button, set that cloned VectorCollection to DataGrid.

Comment: Is there any example or any link please provide it to me.

Comment: Suppose if there is mx datagrid and restore entire dataset and the dataprovider is arrayCollection then How can i do that.

Comment: If the dataProvider is an ArrayCollection, this code can clone ArrayCollection.

`import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
private var _clonedCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
for each ( var _myObj:Object in _originalCollection ) {
 _clonedCollection.addItem(ObjectUtil.copy(_myObj));
}

yourgrid.dataProvider = _clonedCollection;`

Answer (score 0):

1st) Make a copy/backup of your dataProvider's data, not a reference copy, but a true deep copy, do this before you allow the user to start editing.

If you were using an ArrayCollection, you could use the Flex based ObjectUtil:

```
dataGridDataBackup = ObjectUtil.copy(myDataProvidersData) as ArrayCollection;
```

VectorCollection does not have a clone/copy (need to verify this...), but you can easily sub-class it and add a AMF-based (via byteArray) deep-copy, 5/6s line of code for that...

2nd) On your Cancel button click eventHandler:

```
myDataProvidersData.disableAutoUpdate();
myDataProvidersData.removeAll();
myDataProvidersData.addAll(ObjectUtil.copy(dataGridDataBackup) as ArrayCollection);
myDataProvidersData.enableAutoUpdate();
```

Note: This is from memory as I do not have AS3/Flex on this machine but should be pretty close...

**Update:**

Shallow copy a vector:

```
var myNewVector:Vector.<yourvectortype> = orginalVector.concat();
```

Deep copy (just change it to a vector instead of a dynamic object for performance):

```
function deepCopy(source:Object):* { 
    var _ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
    _ba.writeObject(source); 
    _ba.position = 0; 
    return(_ba.readObject()); 
}
```

Note: If you are creating a vector of some complex class/object, you might need to register these class(es)... Again from memory, so adjust as needed...

Comment: How can i make a clone of VectorCollection. Could you please provide  me line of code or any link which help me.

Comment: That is not working i am using the following code.
[Bindable]
public var taskCollection:VectorCollection;

[Bindable]
public var tempArray:VectorCollection = new VectorCollection;

taskCollection.addAllAt(result.taskList , (index * pageLen));
dgTaskResults.dataProvider = new VectorCollection(tempArray.source.slice((start * pageLen),(start * pageLen) + pageLen) );

So please tell me how can i make a clone/copy of taskCollection.